# TypeError: callback is not a function, "node_modules\jsonwebtoken\sign.js:101:14)"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt

When I perform a registration action in Postman, I have the following error in the console:

Error:

> TypeError: callback is not a function,
>   node_modules\jsonwebtoken\sign.js:101:14)

Problem is in this line:

```
const token = jwt.sign({name, email, password}, process.env.JWT_SECRET, process.env.JWT_ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION, {expiresIn: '10m'});
```

**controllers/auth**

```
const User = require('../models/user');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

exports.signup =  (req, res) => {
    const {name, email, password} = req.body;

    User.findOne({email}).exec((err, user) => {
        if (user) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                error: "Email is taken"
            })
        }

        const token = jwt.sign({name, email, password}, process.env.JWT_SECRET, process.env.JWT_ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION, {expiresIn: '10m'});
    });
};
```

**Updated**

When I deleted `process.env.JWT_SECRET`, it works. Do I have to use `process.env.JWT_SECRET`?

Answer (score 0):

Swap process.env.JWT_SECRET's position with process.env.JWT_ACCOUNT and vice versa

Answer (score 0):

jwt.sign basically accept four parameter

- payload
- secret
- options
- callback function

if you change the order in that case you will get this error